# Maximizing Net Profit -with Probabilities

Tags: probability

Every week a grocer has X number of customers who wish to buy a pumpkin, considering that the pumpkins haven't been sold. The random variable X has the following function of mass probability:

```
       Px(x) = (9-x)/10, x=5,6,7,8.
```

At the start of the week the grocer buys pumpkins for 2 euros each,while during the week he sells them for 4 euros. At the end of the week the grocer throws away any unsold pumpkin. If the grocer wishes to maximize his net profit, how many pumpkins will he have to buy?

**My attempt:**

I believe I have to calculate the net profit for each possible x and then compare them. So, for :

```
 x=5 the net income is 10 euros with a possibility of 40%
 x=6 the net income is 12 euros with a possibility of 30%
 x=7 the net income is 14 euros with a possibility of 20%
 x=8 the net income is 16 euros with a possibility of 10%
```

The expected value(E(x)) is 12 ?

I don't know what is the possibility of not selling 1,2,3 or 4 pumpkins.I tried looking at similar problems, like the one with the newspaper boy,but I can't really connect it with my own exercise.Quite frankly I don't know how to continue the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ denote the number of pumpkins the grocer buys. Clearly this number should always be between 5 and 8. Next let $Y_n$ be a random variable that denotes the profit of the grocer given that he buys $n$ pumpkins. Then we want to choose $n$ such that the expected value of $Y_n$ is maximized.

- $n=5$: In this case the grocer always sells all 5 pumpkins and thus $P(Y_n = 5\cdot(4-2) = 10) = 1$ and $E(Y_n) = 10$.
- $n=6$: In this case the grocer has $4/10$ chance that he only sells $5$ pumpkins. Therefore $P(Y_n = 8) = 4/10$ and $P(Y_n = 12) = 6/10$, thus $E(Y_n) = 8\cdot4/10 + 12\cdot6/10 = 10.40$.

etc...